# Grouping together similar items python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that looks like this :

```
       store1 store2 store3 store4 store5
store1    1    0.50   0.65   0.75  -0.35
store2    0.50   1    0.45   0.80   0.22
store3    0.65  0.45    1    0.55   0.85
store4    0.75  0.80  0.55     1    0.35
store5   -0.35  0.22  0.85   0.35    1
```

That is the result of DF.Corr()

I need help on how I can group all similar stores (Threshold = 70+).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by group? please provide starting point of your df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    group = [k+1 for k in range(len(df)) if df.iloc[i,k]>=0.70]
```

Output:

```
[1, 4]
[2, 4]
[3, 5]
[1, 2, 4]
[3, 5]
```

You can then eliminate the repetitive ones. Here you'll be left with [1, 2, 4] and [3, 5].
note, 3 stands for store3

Comment: Thanks Maryam.  That was helpful I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
df1 = (df.gt(0.70)) & (df.ne(1))
groups = df1.dot(df.columns + ',').str.strip(',')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
store1           store4
store2           store4
store3           store5
store4    store1,store2
store5           store3
dtype: object
```